# How to create a cell array of k similar objects in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, initialization, cell

I want to create an 1,k cell of m,m matrices. I have some trouble trying to initialize it. My first idea was to do this

```
myCell = cell{1,K};
for k = 1:K
  myCell{1,k} = eye(m);
end
```

But it seems like such ugly way to initialize it. There have to be a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution with even fewer function calls:

```
[myCell{1:k}] = deal(eye(m));
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a very simple [REPMAT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/repmat.html) solution:

```
myCell = repmat({eye(m)},1,K);
```

This simply creates one cell with `eye(m)` in it, then replicates that cell `K` times.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
myCell =  mat2cell(repmat(eye(m),[1 k]),[m],repmat(m,1,k))
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider this one:

```
myCell = arrayfun(@(x)eye(m), 1:k, 'UniformOutput',false)
```